# how to use ajax with android service?

Tags: java, android, ajax, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want a service to keep request PHP file on server and view a notification if there is a change in the returned value
I never worked in java before, anyone can help me with it?

I searched for ajax code for java and I found this but it's show error when I build the app:

```
package com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

import com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService;

public class MyService extends BackgroundService {

    private final static String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

    private String mHelloTo = "World";

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doWork() {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.106/smarthome/value.php");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result.put("Message", inputLine);
        }

        in.close();

        return result;  
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject getConfig() {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        try {
            result.put("HelloTo", this.mHelloTo);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setConfig(JSONObject config) {
        try {
            if (config.has("HelloTo"))
                this.mHelloTo = config.getString("HelloTo");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

    }     

    @Override
    protected JSONObject initialiseLatestResult() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTimerEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onTimerDisabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

I'm using this plugin for cordova:
https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core

Comment: If you are using cordova, I recommend you to use socket.io for real time and fire base cloud message for the notifications.

Comment: @JorgeMejia thank you for your respond.. but my project use a local server with no internet